# How to read and write comma delimited text files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, vb6

I am currently converting some old VB6 code to VB.net 2013 and am having difficulty reading and writing comma delimited text files. The old VB6 read/write code was straightforward using the Input statement and storing the comma delimited values in the following variables.

```
Open FileName For Input As #1

  Input #1, A, B, C, D
  Input #1, E, F, G, H
  Input #1, I, J, K, L

Close #1
```

The user would then have the ability to save the file changes back to the comma delimited text file using the Write statement as follows:

```
Open FileName For Output As #1

   Write #1, A, B, C, D
   Write #1, E, F, G, H
   Write #1, I, J, K, L

Close #1
```

This should be a fairly simple task in VB.NET but I am having trouble getting it right. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider that  you  have some string value like this
        **Name = "Tom" LastName = "Sanders" Salary = "25000"**
so you should import the System.IO namespace  and then 
write code
 for  write the values to text file same as below

```
Dim Name, LastName, Salary As String
Name = "Tom"
LastName = "Sanders"
Salary = "25000"


Dim wr As StreamWriter
wr = New StreamWriter("C:\SampleTextFile.txt")
wr.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", Name, LastName, Salary))
wr.Flush()
wr = Nothing
```